# Regression : give more importance to specific range of target

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Let's say that I want to predict a value Y that ranges between 0 and 1000. I have for this a set of features denoted X.

How would I force a machine learning model to be better on a specific range of my target. For example, if I want my model to be very good on values between 0 and 100, but it is okay if the model is not that good on values between 100 and 1000.

I am curious to know if there exists such technique. I would said that oversampling over the range of values that I am interested in would be good.

Thanks,

Benoit

Comment: This looks fishy, give some context.

Comment: yes oversampling would work fine. sample weights is the 'api' feature you can look for as well. ( so anything that has additive cost function should be able to support, just whether it is implemented or not) eg in scikitlearn the linear regression supports sample weights but not logistic regression ( though internally the underlying algorithms suppoert sample weights)

Comment: @seanv507, Isn't it in logisitic regression where you can specifiy sample weights and not in regression setting (on sklearn) ?

Comment: @user2974951, what do you mean by fishy ? I can give you an example where you need to be better for small values and not for big one (or the inverse)

Comment: It looks like sample bias.

Comment: Yes ok  it coud come from the data but I was wondering if there were some litterature about that. I did not find anything about it on internet.

Comment: there is no sample weight in logistic regression: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression, but there is in teh underlying code https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0ab589f1541b1ca4570177d93fd7979613497e3/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L79

Comment: Without specifying weights, all weights are implicitly 1.0 by definition - however you can copy a data point and that point will now have an implicit weight of 2.0. This technique can be used to give a crude but very effective weighting when the software used for regression does not directly allow specification of regression weights. I used this technique in Shanghai, China some years ago and my Chinese engineering counterpoint's eyes almost popped out of his head when he realized he could apply this technique to every regression software that he had in his possession, now or in the future.

Comment: It depends on the model and the software.  As a general proposition, though, this is done by *changing the loss function.*  If you have direct control over that, it would be the way to go.  For instance, instead of cross-validating to the sum of squared errors you might double those squared errors for values between 0 and 100.  Changing sample weights typically can accomplish the same thing as this simple form of reweighting, but in general don't provide full control over the loss (or might not really change it at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is weighted regression. See Section 4 in https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes1.pdf for a detailed description.

Like you are hinting, the idea is to weigh samples differently. In the pdf, the points that are close to the point being predicted are weighted higher. What you can do is give higher weights to all your samples whose target value lies in the range you desire. You can also do a soft-weighting where the weight you assign to a sample is inversely proportional to the distance of its target value from your desired range.